# error using gdal_translate with -projwin option

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I have to crop geotiff image, I'm using gdal assembly and I'm trying to use the gdal_translate method

If I crop my image using the -srcwin option all is fine

```
gdal_translate -srcwin 0 0 400 400 imageBase.tiff image_cropped.tiff
```

I have to manage bbox in wgs84 coordinates too, so I try to use -projwin option:

```
gdal_translate -projwin 103.26 23.02 103.36 22.9 imageBase.tiff image_cropped.tiff
```

I get the following error:

```
Input file size is 450, 1047
The -projwin option was used, but the geotransform is
rotated.  This configuration is not supported.
```

My geotiff image has been created programmatically in C# from Jpegcovnerter using tiepoints calculated with my feature image fooprint.

This is the gdalinfo over my geotiff file

```
Size is 450, 1047
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
DATUM["WGS_1984",
    SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
GeoTransform =
103.2667570026355, 0.0005062068032082341, -1.832943060114165e-007
23.02489610024383, -5.790469882757381e-005, -0.0005021561705462942
Metadata:
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
COMPRESSION=JPEG
INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 103.2667570,  23.0248961) (103d16'0.33"E, 23d 1'29.63"N)
Lower Left  ( 103.2665651,  22.4991386) (103d15'59.63"E, 22d29'56.90"N)
Upper Right ( 103.4945501,  22.9988390) (103d29'40.38"E, 22d59'55.82"N)
Lower Right ( 103.4943582,  22.4730815) (103d29'39.69"E, 22d28'23.09"N)
Center      ( 103.3805576,  22.7489888) (103d22'50.01"E, 22d44'56.36"N)
Band 1 Block=450x1047 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=450x1047 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=450x1047 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

I didn't implemented the class building the Tiff so it looks like my geotiff doesn't support the gdal_translate -projwin option.

Do someone have a idea about this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Use gdalwarp first with -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:4326.

Comment: It works because gdalwarp creates a materialized north-up, non-rotated image which is then accepted by gdal_translate for cropping. Actually you can do the same with one step by using gdalwarp with -te parameter http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html.

Comment: When i try to use -te on gdalwarp i get the error: Creating output file that is 178P x -237L.
ERROR 1: Attempt to create 178x-237 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than
 zero.

Comment: Show your parameters, perhaps  xmin ymin xmax ymax are in wrong order and max is smaller than min.

Comment: I tried with gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -te 11495581.442 2635029.678 11520841.369 2568435.324 image_in.tiff image_out_bbox_proj.tiff or gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -dstalpha
te 103.2667570 23.0248961 103.36 22.9 image_in.tiff
image_out.tiff an both give same error response

Comment: In the latter ymin=23.02 and ymax=22.9, don't you see the error?

Comment: Ok i thought it was coordinates of upper left then lower right corner but it's xmin ymin and xmax ymax of the "crop" area. So i invert ymin and ymax. i was the problem ;) thanks for your support.

Comment: @user30184 can you expand your comment/s as an answer to get this Q. off the unanswered list?